# Rectangle won't display in JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, draw

So I've been trying for the last two hours to get this program to draw a simple rectangle in a frame but nothing gets displayed in the frame when i run the program. I've looked through textbooks and old notebooks and everything in my program seems to be fine, yet nothing is displayed. Help?
This is the class that creates the frame and is supposed to draw the rectangle.

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 public class FrameViewer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

     //creates an empty frame.  
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(300,400);
            frame.setTitle("Empty Frame");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //draws the rectangle within the frame.
            RectangleComponent component = new RectangleComponent();
            frame.add(component);
            frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

And here is the RectangleComponent

```
         import javax.swing.JComponent;
         import java.awt.Graphics;
         import java.awt.Graphics2D;
         import java.awt.Rectangle;

         public class RectangleComponent extends JComponent{
            public void paintCOmponent(Graphics g){
              Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
              Rectangle box = new Rectangle(5,10,20,30);
              g2.draw(box);

}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Java is case sensitive, instead of

```
paintCOmponent
```

You want

```
paintComponent
```

You should use the `@Override` annotation to mark methods you think you are overriding as it will highlight problems like this.

The method should also remain `protected`, as there is no reason any one should be calling from outside the class

You may also want to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)